# SQL - Transactional replication, can consumer content be updated from other clients

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactional-replication

We are investigating the possibility to use transactional replication for an archive / reporting database in order to offload the production database. 
If we use the same software/client for accessing the archive, the client will update some tables in the archive/consumer like access logs i.e. primary keys/identifiers will not match the production database (which is not an application problem). The log function only adds rows to a table.
Is this possible or will the transactional replication fail? Other issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Enterprise Edition of SQL Server, please look at [Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196.aspx), that may fit the bill, allowing you to have changes made at the subscriber sync'd with the publisher (each node is a republisher).

Answer (score 0):

I did the trial-and-error method and configured a transactional replication which was not that obvious but it seems to work. I then tried to add rows to a table in the subscriber / archive database and also to the same table in the producer side. What will happen is that there will be a primary key violation since the IDENTITY ranges are the same on both sides. One way to handle this is described here, [PK Violation after transactional replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733138/pk-violation-after-transactional-replication)

Comment: are you saying you do not require the publisher/subscriber to be in sync?